# Issue in 2.3.3 when posting to Facebook from my android application

Tags: android

I have an android app that posts to users wall by using the Facebook for android API. When user presses a button a dialog to log in to Facebook and then share a predefined text to his FB-wall. This works perfect in the emulator in every version from 2.1 through 2.3.3, and also with devices tested with 2.2. However on devices with 2.3.3 (tested with HTC-salsa), Facebook is just loading and then is suddenly finished and the previous activity (with the button) is displayed(FB dialog closed), and nothing gets posted on facebook wall. thanxs in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. download and install "Git-1.7.7.1-preview20111027.exe" file
2. Windows>Preferences>Android>Build and get the path of the debug keystore
3. open command prompt and run the following command

   ```
   keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "debug keystore path" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
   ```

and add debug keystore path, and add openssl path like

```
C:\> keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\User\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\openssl" enc -a -e
```

then, it will ask for the password; enter "`android`" as your password.
Now add the HASH KEY to your Facebook API configuration located http://www.facebook.com/developers/ under EDIT SETTINGS / Mobile and Devices screen.